# A Strong Chernoff Bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, information-theory

In this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/165.pdf) by Winter et al, it is stated that the following 'Chernoff bound' holds for $i.i.d.$ random variables $X_k$ such that $0 \leq X_k \leq 1$ and $E(X_k) = p$ for all $k$,

$$\Pr \left[ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N X_k \geq (1+\eta)p \right]\leq \exp(-\frac{N\eta^2p}{2\ln 2}),$$
and
$$\Pr \left[ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N X_k \leq (1-\eta)p \right]\leq \exp(-\frac{N\eta^2p}{2\ln 2}),$$
even without a condition on the varibale $\eta$.
However, this $2\ln2$ exponent is the smallest among the variants of the Chernoff bounds (usually it's $2$ or $3$) I've ever seen, and I can't find a proof for this version. Is this Chernoff bound even true? How can one prove this version?

Comment: Winter is an information theorist, and this is from 2003, so I'm pretty sure that all the logs and exps in a paper of his will be base 2 (you should check this, they will certainly mention this). So the bound they give gains an extra $\ln(2)$ in the denominator of the exponent for this reason. I'm pretty sure $\eta>0$ is needed, otherwise taking $\eta<0$ in the first bound contradicts the second. I do suspect the $2$ in the denominator of the upper tail - basically as $\eta$ grows big you should start seeing a exponent that is linear in $\eta$

Comment: essentially due to behaviour captured in the Bernstein bound, and the form of the bound above doesn't show this. As for the $0 \le X \le 1$ instead of Bernoulli $X$, this is simple, because for a given mean, the Bernoulli will have the biggest fluctuations. More formally if $X$ is as in the question and $B$ is Bernoulli with same mean, then $P(X \ge x) \le P(B \ge x)$ is true for any $x,$ and the sums of many $X$s are similarly dominated by sums of many Bernoullis, so you only need to argue for Bernoullis.

Comment: Altogether not all that big a deal, just another paper being sloppy in details that are relatively unimportant. Unless they actually use the upper tail behaviour for large $\eta$, you should just mentally correct and get on with things.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks, I, too, wanted to just shrug it off but it looked like some minor steps in the paper's argument depend on the extra $ln 2$ factor. But as it seems like that the Hoeffding inequality fits more than the Chernoff bound for the following arguments, I found the inner peace.

Comment: I know that feeling, lol. It's unfortunate that there's no nice notation for $2^{*}$ that doesn't have all the action going on in a subscript unlike $\exp(*)$. Hoeffding, btw, would have a $p^2$ in the exponent instead of a $p$. I'd have expected that to be a lot more harmful than a $\ln(2)$ factor...